# Writing a HTTP server in C

Tags: beginner, c, http, socket

## Code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

char *get_file(char *request)
{

    int end, start, i;
    end = 4;
    start = 4;
    i = 4;

    while (*(request + i) != ' ')
    {
        end += 1;
        i += 1;
    }
    char *file = malloc(end - start + 1);
    memcpy(file, request + start, end - start);
    file[end - start] = '\0';

    return file;
}

void process_respond(char **reply, char *file)
{
    char *mine_type = strchr(file, '.');
    int lent = 18;
    *reply = (char *)malloc(18);
    bzero(*reply, 18);
    strcat(*reply, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n");

    if (!mine_type)
    {
        *reply = (char *)realloc(*reply, lent + strlen("Content-Type: text/html\n\n"));
        strcat(*reply, "Content-Type: text/html\n\n");
    }
    else if (strcmp(mine_type, ".html") == 0)
    {
        *reply = (char *)realloc(*reply, lent + strlen("Content-Type: text/html\n\n"));
        strcat(*reply, "Content-Type: text/html\n\n");
    }
    else if (strcmp(mine_type, ".js") == 0)
    {
        *reply = (char *)realloc(*reply, lent + strlen("Content-Type: text/javascript\n\n"));
        strcat(*reply, "Content-Type: text/javascript\n\n");
    }
    else if (strcmp(mine_type, ".png") == 0)
    {
        *reply = (char *)realloc(*reply, lent + strlen("Content-Type: image/png\n\n"));
        strcat(*reply, "Content-Type: image/png\n\n");
    }
    else if (strcmp(mine_type, ".gif") == 0)
    {
        *reply = (char *)realloc(*reply, lent + strlen("Content-Type: image/gif\n\n"));
        strcat(*reply, "Content-Type: image/gif\n\n");
    }
    else if (strcmp(mine_type, ".svg") == 0)
    {
        *reply = (char *)realloc(*reply, lent + strlen("Content-Type: image/svg+xml\n\n"));
        strcat(*reply, "Content-Type: image/svg+xml\n\n");
    }

    else if (strcmp(mine_type, ".css") == 0)
    {
        *reply = (char *)realloc(*reply, lent + strlen("Content-Type: text/css\n\n"));
        strcat(*reply, "Content-Type: text/css\n\n");
    }

    else if (strcmp(mine_type, ".jpg") == 0)
    {
        *reply = (char *)realloc(*reply, lent + strlen("Content-Type: image/jpeg\n\n"));
        strcat(*reply, "Content-Type: image/jpeg\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        *reply = (char *)realloc(*reply, lent + strlen("Content-Type: text/html\n\n"));
        strcat(*reply, "Content-Type: text/html\n\n");
    }
}

int read_file_to_buffer(char *file, char **buffer, int *size_of_buffer)
{

    FILE *fptr;
    char public_dir[256] = "./public";
    if (strcmp(file, "/") == 0)
    {
        fptr = fopen("./public/index.html", "r");
    }
    else
    {
        strcat(public_dir, file);
        fptr = fopen(public_dir, "r");
    }

    if (!fptr)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    fseek(fptr, 0L, SEEK_END);
    *size_of_buffer = ftell(fptr);
    fseek(fptr, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    *buffer = (char *)malloc(*size_of_buffer);

    fread(*buffer, *size_of_buffer, 1, fptr);

    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;

    // What happened if we send a file that is too large?
}

void handle_sigint(int sig)
{
    exit(-1);
    printf("Server setting down\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGINT, handle_sigint);
    int sockfd, client_socketfd, client_len, portno;
    char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr; // server address

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        error("Error when creating socket");
    }

    bzero(&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
    portno = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = portno;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
    {
        error("Can not bind the address to the socket");
    }

    listen(sockfd, 5);

    client_len = sizeof(client_addr);

    while (1)
    {
        int new_sockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_len);
        if (new_sockfd < 0)
        {
            error("Error on accept");
        }

        bzero(&buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH);
        if (read(new_sockfd, &buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH) < 0)
        {
            error("Can't not read message");
        }
        char *file = get_file(buffer);

        char *buffer_file;
        int size_of_buffer = 0;

        char *reply;

        int n = read_file_to_buffer(file, &buffer_file, &size_of_buffer);

        if (n == 0)
        {
            process_respond(&reply, file);

            if (write(new_sockfd, reply, strlen(reply)) < 0)
            {
                error("Can not write to the socket");
            }
            pid_t pid = fork();

            if (pid < 0)
            {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else if (pid == 0)
            {

                if (write(new_sockfd, buffer_file, size_of_buffer) < 0)
                {
                    error("Can not write to the socket");
                }
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            else
            {
                wait(&pid);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            char *fail_message = "HTTP/1.1 400 Not Found\n"
                                 "Content-Type: text/html\n"
                                 "Content-Length: 27\n"
                                 "Connection: close\n"
                                 "\n"
                                 "Can not find the resources\n";

            if (write(new_sockfd, fail_message, strlen(fail_message)) < 0)
            {
                error("Can not write to the socket");
            }
        }

        if (buffer_file)
            free(buffer_file);
        if (file)
            free(file);
        if (reply)
            free(reply);

        if (close(new_sockfd) < 0)
        { // After close socket will have somtime before it unbind from a port
            error("Can not close listening socket");
        }
    }

    if (close(sockfd) < 0)
    {
        error("Can not close socket");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

## Review request

I am currently learning how to write a simple HTTP server in C. My experience with C is still at beginner level, so I am looking for style, bad practices, and security issues.

Comment: None of those `realloc()` calls are checked for failure before using the possibly-null pointer that's returned.  You really need to fix that first.

Comment: Also, it's full of security issues such as failing to check the length of the path, and lacking any checking for `..` path compents (which should be done _after_ decoding `%` escape sequences).

Answer (score 3):

The BSD standard provides some goodies in [`err.h`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/err.3.html). If the header is available on your system, you may be able to replace your custom `error()` function with BSD's `err()` (or some other version thereof).

That being said, the argument to `error()` should be of type `const char *` as it is not modified anywhere in the function.

---

```
bzero(*reply, 18);
```

From [Linux's man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bcopy.3.html) of `bcopy()`:

> Marked as LEGACY in POSIX.1-2001: use memcpy(3) or memmove(3) in
> new programs.  Note that the first two arguments are interchanged
> for memcpy(3) and memmove(3).  POSIX.1-2008 removes the
> specification of bcopy().

In other words, replace it with `memcpy()`/`memmove()`.

---

The name `get_file()` appears rather ambiguous. I also do not understand what these magic values:

```
int end, start, i;
end = 4;
start = 4;
i = 4;
```

mean. Furthermore, the return value of `malloc()` goes unchecked in the function. In case of an error, `malloc()` returns a null pointer. Failure to check for it risks invoking undefined behavior by a subsequent null pointer dereference. The call to `memcpy()` following `malloc()` *technically* invokes undefined behavior too, because `file` might be `NULL`, and the [C standard 7.1.4](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) states:

> If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as a value
> outside the domain of the function, or a pointer outside the address
> space of the program, or a null pointer, or a pointer to
> non-modifiable storage when the corresponding parameter is not
> const-qualified) or a type (after promotion) not expected by a
> function with variable number of arguments, **the behavior is undefined.**

Here too the passed in `char *` is not modified, so this should be declared with the `const` qualifier too.

---

```
void handle_sigint(int sig)
{
    exit(-1);
    printf("Server setting down\n");
}
```

is plain undefined behavior.

According to §7.14.2.1:

> If the signal occurs other than as the result of calling the abort or
> raise function, **the behavior is undefined** if the signal handler refers
> to any object with static or thread storage duration that is not a
> lock-free atomic object other than by assigning a value to an object
> declared as volatile sig_atomic_t, or the signal handler calls any
> function in the standard library other than — the abort function, —
> the _Exit function, — the quick_exit function, — the functions in
> <stdatomic.h> (except where explicitly stated otherwise) when the
> atomic arguments are lock-free, — the atomic_is_lock_free function
> with any atomic argument, or — the signal function with the first
> argument equal to the signal number corresponding to the signal that
> caused the invocation of the handler. Furthermore, if such a call to
> the signal function results in a SIG_ERR return, the value of errno is
> indeterminate.

These functions are async-signal-unsafe even in the POSIX standard. As alternatives, the POSIX standard does specify that `_exit()`, `_Exit()`, and `write()` are safe to be called in a signal handler.

But how do you report an error if `write()` fails and there's no other possible way to report an error? You don't.

But really, you shouldn't be using `signal()` in the first place. According to [Linux's man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html):

> WARNING: the behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions,
> and has also varied historically across different versions of
> Linux.  **Avoid its use: use sigaction(2) instead.**

I do not see why printing "Server setting down\n" on a `SIGINT` is necessary, or even useful. It is only serving to introduce more complexity in the code. And then you're exiting with an error status of -1 - which is another magic value - instead of `EXIT_FAILURE` from `stdlib.h`.

Ideally, the signal handler should only set a file-scope flag variable of type `volatile sig_atomic_t` which would be checked in `main()` before each iteration.

Though, you should disable `SIGHUP` because a closed connection would generate a send/recv error, which would kill the server process.

For which `signal()` suffices, as the man page says:

> The only portable use of signal() is to set a signal's
> disposition to SIG_DFL or SIG_IGN.

---

Here's another problematic part of the code:

```
portno = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
```

Ignoring what the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html) of `atoi()` says in the BUGS portion, we're accessing `argv[1]` without checking whether `argc` was greater than 1. Your program calls `htons(atoi(argv[1]))` with a null pointer when I run it without providing any arguments, so this too is undefined behavior.

---

You are exiting if `bind()` fails, and leaking the `sockfd` file descriptor.

---

The return value of `listen()` is ignored. Execution should not continue if `listen()` failed.

---

```
 char public_dir[256] = "./public";
 if (strcmp(file, "/") == 0)
 {
     fptr = fopen("./public/index.html", "r");
```

Consider defining macros for these strings so that they can be edited easily and in one place.

---

In `read_file_to_buffer()`, the return value of `malloc()` and `fread()` goes unchecked. Consider using `true` and `false` from `stdbool.h` instead of 0 and -1 for the return value.

---

In `main()`, `fail_message` should be of type `const char *`.

I doubt it matters much if we failed to close the server socket before exiting the program.

I would have expected to see `send()`/`recv()` in networking code rather than `read()`/`write()`.

Calling `exit()` in the child branch of a `fork()` is a good way of
calling the functions registered with `atexit()`, flushing `stdio` buffers, deleting temporary files created with `tmpfile()` et cetera. [Why use _exit rather than exit in the child branch of a fork?](https://www.unixguide.net/unix/programming/1.1.3.shtml)

---

In `process_response()`, the return value of `strchr()` goes unchecked. It may very well return a null pointer, dereferencing which would later invoke undefined behavior.

Then we have another magic value:

```
int lent = 18;
*reply = (char *)malloc(18);
bzero(*reply, 18);
```

This too holds no meaning to me. What is 18, and what does it denote?

The return value of `malloc()` goes unused here as well. There's also a needless cast. Starting with C89 (which is a 35 year old standard) `malloc()` and family returns a generic `void *` that is implicitly converted to and from any other pointer type. As such, its result need not be casted and only serves to clutter the code.

Then we have a lot of duplicate code. I'd refactor that into, perhaps, a table and pre-compute the lengths of the content-type headers.

`realloc()` is used incorrectly in the code. The return value should not be stored in the same pointer that is being reallocated. If `realloc()` fails, which you don't check for by ignoring the return value, it would return a null pointer which would overwrite the pointer to the original chunk of memory, and we'd have a memory leak in the code, and on subsequent requests, more memory leaks.

---

There's a `BUFFER_LENGTH` in `main()` whose definition I do not see in any part of the code.

---

`*(request + i)` is typically written as `request[i]`.

---

`main()` is too long and does too much. Break it into smaller functions.

Comment: Thank you. Your review is really detailed and concise.